# How to set element class in parent component from each child component?

Tags: angular

In app.component (the main one of the application) I have:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Header
================================================== -->
    <header  class="transparent sticky-header full-width">
.
.
.
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
                <nav-menu></nav-menu>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
                <flash-messages></flash-messages>
                <ng2-toasty></ng2-toasty>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

I want the header to keep "transparent" class only on home.component. On all the other components I want to keep the other two classes, without "transparent".

A hierarchy that should explain better how the components are structured can be seen in the below picture:

[image]

So, the home component is not the parent, but app.component is the parent. home.component is a child as are the others.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastyService } from "ng2-toasty";
import { AppErrorHandler } from "../../app.error-handler";
import { HomeComponent } from "../home/home.component";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [
        HomeComponent,
        ToastyService,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler }
    ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    classes: string;
    constructor(private home: HomeComponent, private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
        //this.classes = false;
        //if (this.router.url ==='/home')
        //{
        //    this.classes = true;
        //}
        this.classes = "transparent sticky- header full- width";
    }
}
```

I have tried to make a variable classes and pass it with ngClass, but it does not work.

I have searched for solutions and all I've found were based on events.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Are your other components child components of this home component (embedded into the home component via their selectors) or child routes (home component contains a router outlet for the children) or are the components not related at all?

Comment: All of the components have the header of app.component. I want this header to have "transparent" class if I am on the home.component and not on the other components. The home component is not related to the others.

Comment: I will update it now to give more information

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to add another component named `Main Component` in this drawing.

[image]

The top image sounds like what you have now. The bottom image is an alternative approach.

You could instead *remove* the header and anything else you don't want on *every* page from the app.component and only have the `router-link`.

Then you could add a `Main Component` that would contain everything that you want on every other page. It would then contain a `router-outlet` that would host every other page of the application that does need a header.

ALTERNATIVELY

You could try using ngClass. That allows you to specify CSS classes based on a value. Here is an example of one of mine:

```
<span  [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign': !isValid('tags')}">
```

This turns on the defined style classes if the `isValid(...)` method returns false.

You would then need to define some property to bind to and ensure that property is set when appropriate. You could probably do that with a service.

Answer (score 0):

use of a global css file instead of per component css may solve your problem. You can customize this behavior using ViewEncapsulation .